# How to remove spot on top of curio cabinet

Tags: furniture

I have a curio cabinet with an area on left side that is raised up above surface in a few spots. Based on the picture, can someone give me some advice as to how to remove this spot. I had tried Goo Gone to remove it but it didn't do much good.[image]

Comment: Try a scouring pad https://www.lowes.com/pd/Scotch-Brite-3-Pack-Cellulose-Scouring-Pad/1053709

Comment: It looks like maybe it was repaired at one time and not a "perfect" repair. Try scour pad, steel wool 000 or a 1000 grit or higher wet sandpaper.